# How to stop the data bricks notebook automatically after 10 mins

Tags: databricks

How to stop the databricks notebook automatically after 10 mins?

I want to cancel my databricks notebooks automatically if it running more than 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

If you run the notebook as a job you can specify a timeout duration. The job will get the status "Timed out" if it takes longer than that duration. Please see the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/settings.html#configure-a-timeout-for-a-job).

If you're running the notebook interactively then it is not directly possible, however you can call your notebook interactively from another notebook using `dbutils.notebook.run()`. This will allow you to set a timeout once again. For example if you have notebookA and notebookB in the same folder you can run notebookB from notebookA using the code below.

```
# NotebookA
timeout = 600
dbutils.notebook.run('./notebookB', timeout)
```

In the background this will create an ephemeral job. Please see the documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#dbutilsnotebook-api).